# Built-in case insensitive string=

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to compare two strings ignoring the case for the `assoc` `:test` function. I know that I can easily write the function like so:

```
(defun cistring= (str1 str2)
  (string= (string-downcase str1)
           (string-downcase str2)))
```

However I was wondering: **Is there is a built-in case insensitive `string=`?** Or maybe I just cannot find any?

Comment: [`STRING-EQUAL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm)

Comment: Bah... you are right... How did I missed it? BTW post an answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`STRING-EQUAL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) compares strings case insensitively (characters are `CHAR-EQUAL`).

```
CL-USER> (string-equal "foo" "FOO")
T
CL-USER> (string-equal "foo" "FOOBAR" :end2 3)
T
```